# ClientContext throwing 401 error on local host otherwise working fine

Tags: 2013

When I run this code on server XYZ it works fine, but when I run it on server where site collection exists... I get 401 error, any idea ?

```
        using (ClientContext webContext = new ClientContext(fileUri.ToString()))
        {
            webContext.Load(webContext.Web);
            webContext.ExecuteQuery();

            string webURL = webContext.Web.Url;
            string webRelURL = webContext.Web.ServerRelativeUrl;
            string relativePath = $"{webRelURL}{path.Replace(webURL, string.Empty)}";
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(webContext, relativePath, content, true);

        }
```

Comment: What will be the value of `fileUri`?

Comment: same url works on other server, it's just a url to site collection's sub web

Comment: Can you try with `NetworkCredentials` and let me know. Just for diagnosis.

Comment: I fixed the issue, local host was going through a proxy server because of host files pointing to it, removed that and it works, thank you everyone :)